# Convergence of $\sum\sqrt{a_n}$ and $\sum\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n}$ when $\sum_{n=1}a_n,\ a_n>0$ is a convergent series

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\sum_{n=1}a_n,\ a_n>0$ be a convergent series. Consider following statements:

- P: The series $\sum_{n=1}\sqrt{a_n}$ is always convergent
- Q: The series $\sum_{n=1} \frac{a_1 + a_2 +...+a_n}{n}$ is always divergent

Then

1. Both P and Q are true,
2. P is true but Q is false,
3. Both P and Q are false,
4. P is false and Q is true

I was thinking of suitable examples/counterexamples but I could not find any. Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Which examples, suitable or not, did you try?

Comment: @Did Like $\frac{1}{n^2}$. I think A is false due to this example

Comment: Hint for the second series: The $n$-th term is $\ge \frac{a_1}{n}$.

Comment: So... it seems the first example which came to your mind (namely, $a_n=1/n^2$) was suitable to fully solve the exercise, right?

Comment: @Did For first statement, yes

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. For P. Let $a_n=\frac{1}{n^2}$ as you guessed. Then $\sum_{n=1}\frac1{n^2}$ converges, while $$\sum_{n=1}\sqrt{\frac1{n^2}}=\sum_{n=1}\frac1{n}$$ does not.
2. For Q. Since $a_n>0$ for all $n\in \mathbb N$, you have that $$\sum_{n=1}\frac{a_1+\ldots+a_n}{n}>\sum_{n=1}\frac{a_1}{n}=a_1\sum_{n=1}\frac1n$$ which diverges. So, by comparison the LHS always diverges.

In sum, P is false, Q is true.